# NSImageView non-uniform scaling not possible with NSAffineTransform in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsimageview

I have been browsing the Internet for two days now, and apparently I'm missing something. I am trying to achieve a skewing effect for a `NSImageView`. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752331/how-do-i-create-an-nsaffinetransform-with-a-skew-effect) on stack overflow, which suggests that it is possible. Also, in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIIICJI) it suggests that a NSAffineTransform with a `NSAffineTransformStruct` is allowed.

Nevertheless: it doesn't work. The only thing I am able to perform are `NSAffineTransform rotateByDegrees`, `NSAffineTransform scaleXBy:foo yBy:foo`. Everything else doesn't show any apparent effect. I don't get any errors, just no result.

So my question is: is non-uniform scaling using `NSAffineTransform` not allowed for Apps on OSX? And if so, why doesn't Xcode (at least) warn me for this? Or am I missing something here (like a programming mistake)?

Any help would be appreciated!

The code I'm using:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

// Drawing code here.
NSAffineTransform *rotate = [[NSAffineTransform alloc] init];
NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];

[context saveGraphicsState];
[currentImage lockFocus];
[rotate setTransformStruct:currentTransForm]; //This is filled in another routine
[rotate concat];

/* Your drawing code [NSImage drawAtPoint....]for the image goes here
 Also, if you need to lock focus when drawing, do it here.       */
CGRect imageRect = dirtyRect;

[self.image drawInRect:imageRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
[self.image unlockFocus];
[context restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Comment: But where do you apply the transform or rotate to the image ?

Comment: It's in a subclass of NSImageView. But I found the problem: it was due to the lockFocus. It drawed on the image itself, in stead of the screen. It's actually working now. Thank you, nevertheless!